# How to download Stanford Open Classroom videos?

Tags: video, downloads, offline

I am using **Ubuntu 11.10** & want to download **Stanford Open Classroom** videos..basically for offline viewing,

Ex: **http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=WebApplications**

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox with [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) addon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the following code in a new document and save it in a new directory as *downloader.py*.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import urllib
   from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


   COURSE_URL = 'http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=WebApplications'

   def download_video(video_name):
       course_name = COURSE_URL.split('course=')[1]
       request = urllib.urlopen('http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/'\
                                'courses/{0}/videos/{1}.xml'.format(course_name,
                                                                    video_name))
       response = request.read()

       flv_name = response.split('<videoFile>')[1].split('</videoFile>')[0]
       print 'Downloading: %s' % flv_name
       urllib.urlretrieve('http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/'\
                          '{0}/videos/{1}'.format(course_name, flv_name),
                           flv_name)

   def main():
       request = urllib.urlopen(COURSE_URL)
       response = request.read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

       results = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'results-list'})
       for result in results:
           lists = result.findAll('li')
           for li in lists:
               urls = li.findAll('a')
               for url in urls:
                   video_name = str(url).split('video=')[1].split('&')[0]
                   download_video(video_name)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
2. Open a new terminal (press *Alt+F2* and enter '*terminal*') and make sure you have the *python-beautifulsoup* package installed by entering:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
   ```
3. Navigate to the directory where the *downloader.py* file is located (using the '*cd*' command).
4. Run the file using the *python* command:

   ```
   python downloader.py
   ```
5. Wait until all the video files are downloaded. They should appear in the same directory where the *downloader.py* file is located.
6. If you want to download other course, you would have to change the 'COURSE_URL' variable in the *downloader.py* file with the URL address of the course you want to download.

Comment: I parallelized this to download 10 videos at a time, and changed it to ask for a directory to save in and to ask for the course url. See here: https://github.com/mdenton8/Openclassroom-Downloader

Comment: I wrote another one and now see your post. Mine works on python 3.5 and is very simple and similar to yours https://github.com/AlmogCohen/open_classroom_downloader

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
youtube-dl 'SOMEURL'
```

e.g.

```
youtube-dl 'http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/VideoPage.php?course=ufldl&video=03.1-NeuralNetworks-Representation&speed=100'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote my own simple downloader based on python 3.5 and the simple requests library. No magic there. [Check it out](https://github.com/AlmogCohen/open_classroom_downloader)

just run `python downloader.py`, select your course and enjoy the parallel download :)

The script will first fetch the full course list and will let you choose. Then after you choose it will fetch the course description and will download all of it's videos into a folder named as the course name.

Comment: This answer solves the problem, but it could be improved with a description of what the script does, any dependencies it may have, and example usages.